# openvpnサーバーでエラーが発生する

Tags: vpn

サーバーに接続しようとするとサーバー側で以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Opening utun failed (connect(AF_SYS_CONTROL)): Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Failed to open utun device. Falling back to /dev/tun device
```

**環境**
OS: MacOS Ventura 13.5.1 (Apple M1)
OpenVPN Version: OpenVPN 2.6.8 aarch64-apple-darwin22.6.0 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [MH/RECVDA] [AEAD]

##### 検索して既に試した方法

- sudoを付けて実行する
- openvpnの実行ファイルにフルディスクアクセスを付与する